# Flask: Work around a timeout error while running long data collection process

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, concurrency, flask

I have a Flask app that will run on `OpenShift`, that takes a while to generate data and can lead to a timeout error.

From looking at examples, I thought that I could render a "please wait" template which returns immediately, while also calling my long running,  `run_analysis()` function. When the data was finished being collected, `run_analysis()` would render a new page.

Either this isn't possible or I'm doing it wrong.  Thanks for your help.

```
from flask import Flask
import jinja2

app = Flask(__name__)

please_wait_template = jinja2.Template('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>please wait for data</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Collecting data, this could take a while.</h1>
</body>
</html>''')

input_template = jinja2.Template('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Input Keywords</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Doing stuff</h1>
    <form action="/please_wait/"  method="POST">
        Enter keywords<br>
        <input type="text" name="kw" placeholder="data science"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>''')

output_template = jinja2.Template("""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>results</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>RESULTS</h1>
    {{ results }}
</body>

</html>
""")

@app.route('/')
def render_input_page():
    return input_template.render()

@app.route('/please_wait/')
def please_wait():
    return please_wait_template.render()

@app.route('/please_wait/', methods=['post'])
def run_analysis():
    kws = request.form['kw']
    zips = request.form['zipcodes']
    template = run_long_analysis(kws, zips)

    return template

def run_long_analysis(kws, zips):
    import time
    time.sleep(2400)
    return output_template(results="testing")
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible. You will want to break out of the single file however. i.e. creating a templates directory and storing your templates there. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Quoting the docs basic example:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/hello/')
@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('hello.html', name=name)
```

You can see `render_template` is used instead of the `.render()` or `output_template`. This is convenient and it makes reading the Flask logic easier.

---

Specifically to your code:

```
@app.route('/please_wait/', methods=['post'])
def run_analysis():
    kws = request.form['kw']
    zips = request.form['zipcodes']
    template = run_long_analysis(kws, zips)
```

The line `zips = request.form['zipcodes']` would be troublesome, because I don't see a form under the *please_wait* route. Perhaps you realize that though.

---

In general, a tool that will help in situations like this, in my experience is the Flask `session` object. Which is basically a global dictionary that persists across a user session. See more here in the docs http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions.

Quoting that example:

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'Logged in as %s' % escape(session['username'])
    return 'You are not logged in'

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['username'] = request.form['username']
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return '''
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=username>
            <p><input type=submit value=Login>
        </form>
    '''

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # remove the username from the session if it's there
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

# set the secret key.  keep this really secret:
app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'
```

You can see in the above example that the `session` object behaves like a dict. It also allows you to dynamically change content displayed, via *Jinja2*. In other words, it can be passed into the template. These methods in conjunction, should give you the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: I've started using template files and using a session. Thanks that is helpful. However, I'm not seeing how to render a template and start the data gathering function, and then updating the rendered template.

Comment: Jinja2 conditionals. See here http://jinja.pocoo.org/. Depending on how complicated your "data gathering" function actually is, you will need to think about concurrency, e.g. https://curio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ (an interesting one I've been reading about lately). I have no experience with curio, the way I see it being helpful to your problem is while computing stuff related to the function, you can tell curio to also do other stuff first, and then once the computation finishes add in its result to the template (as I see it, via a session variable). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I thought that the jinja conditionals were filled in after the function call was finished ? I'll try and see what happens !

Comment: I think, yes, the functions need to evaluate first. But with a concurrency tool, you could work around that. I'm not sure how exactly though, I'm just learning about concurrency myself. Hopefully some more experienced users will comment on this.